# How to add dbmate to existing project?

Tags: python, postgresql, jetbrains-ide

`dbmate` ([link](https://github.com/amacneil/dbmate)) is an awesome CLI tool to manage schema migrations in SQL databases.  Our team has adopted it, but we have some pre-existing projects that already have PostgreSQL databases.  `dbmate` is great if used from the onset of a project, but is there any straightforward way to port a pre-existing database into `dbmate`?  Can't find anything about it on the docs.

We have JetBrains tools like DataGrip/PyCharm pro at our disposable, so if there's some way to export the DB into a schema file that `dbmate` could then somehow manage, even if hacky, that solution would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run `dbmate dump` to get the existing schema and add it to a "fake" migration. Here's how:

1. Run `dbmate dump` which will generate `db/schema.sql` - rename it to `import.sql`
2. Run `dbmate new import` which will generate an "import" migration
3. Run `dbmate new start` which will generate a "start" migration
4. Add anything you like to the "start" migration or leave it blank
5. Run `dbmate up`
6. Modify `import.sql` if necessary and then move its contents to the "import" migration

Now the dbmate "cursor" is on the "start" migration, as if the "import" migration already happened. You can continue making new migrations on top of the existing schema.

This was also a [question on dbmate's GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/amacneil/dbmate/issues/96).